# Finding if a SSL certificate is Signed

Tags: android, ssl, x509trustmanager

I am new to android. I have written code for ios and want similar algo in android.

Here is the scene. I have 2 types of servers- 1. with self signed cert 2. with signed cert.

Now in ios I use following steps to decide whether it is signed or not.

STACK_OF(X509) *stX509Certificate = SSL_get_peer_cert_chain(ssl);
    int cert_num = sk_X509_num(stX509Certificate);

```
CFMutableArrayRef certArray = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, cert_num, NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < cert_num; i++) {
    unsigned char *raw = NULL;

    X509 *x509Certificate = sk_X509_value(stX509Certificate, i);
    int rawlen = i2d_X509(x509Certificate, &raw);
    CFDataRef cfcert = CFDataCreate(NULL, raw, rawlen);
    free(raw);

    SecCertificateRef secCertRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, cfcert);
    CFRelease(cfcert);

    CFArrayAppendValue(certArray, secCertRef);
}

CFStringRef servAddr = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, [[srvSplit objectAtIndex:0] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
SecPolicyRef secPolRef = SecPolicyCreateSSL(YES, servAddr);
CFRelease(servAddr);

SecTrustRef secTruRef ;
SecTrustResultType secTrustRes;
Boolean isCertTrusted = NO;
if(SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certArray, secPolRef, &secTruRef) == errSecSuccess) {
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(secTruRef, NO);
    if (SecTrustEvaluate(secTruRef,&secTrustRes) == errSecSuccess) {
        switch (secTrustRes) {
            case kSecTrustResultInvalid:
            case kSecTrustResultDeny:
            case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure:
            case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure:
            case kSecTrustResultOtherError:
                isCertTrusted = NO;
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultUnspecified:
            case kSecTrustResultProceed:
                isCertTrusted = YES;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In android I cant find such `TrustEvaluate` method. I tried `getBasicConstraints` and `getKeyUsage`. But I cant distinguish between signed and other certs.

Please help me.

Comment: I hope you are aware of what you are trying to do. Hope you have read [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it may not similar to your IOS algo but it works fine.

- Add your self signed certificate in /res/raw
- First this code checks android system certificates(Trusted credentials) in this case if you are connecting to CA certified server, it verifies your certificate and allows you to connect the server
- If you are trying to connect self signed server it checks your self signed certificate which is in /res/raw
- If you are trying to connect self signed server with IP address then your certificate should contain **subjectAltName**

  ```
  public class CheckCertificate{

  private static class NewCustomTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{

  private X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager;
  private X509TrustManager localTrustManager;
  public NewCustomTrustManager(KeyStore localKeyStore) throws KeyStoreException {
      try {
          this.defaultTrustManager = createNewTrustManager(null);
          this.localTrustManager = createNewTrustManager(localKeyStore);
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private X509TrustManager createNewTrustManager(KeyStore store) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {           
      String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();            
      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
      tmf.init(store);            
      TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
      return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
  }
  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
      try {
          //Checks system certificate
          defaultTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
      } catch (CertificateException ce) {
          //Checks your self signed certificate
          localTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
  }



  @Override
  public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      X509Certificate[] first = defaultTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
      X509Certificate[] second = localTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
      X509Certificate[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
      return result;
    }
   }
   public static void setCustomCertificate(Context cn) {

  try {
      // Load CAs from an InputStream
      // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
      CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");          
      InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(cn.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.apache_25));

      try {
          ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

      }catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
          caInput.close();
      }

      // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
      String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
      keyStore.load(null, null);
      keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cacertificate", ca);

      // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore and system CA
      NewCustomTrustManager trustManager = new NewCustomTrustManager(keyStore);

      // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);

      // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
      HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

  } catch (CertificateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }

  }
  ```